# NetSparkle vs SparkleDotNET

Tags: .net, auto-update

I want to add an autoupdate feature to my application and I discovered [NetSparkle](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) and [SparkleDotNET](https://github.com/iKenndac/SparkleDotNET).

Anyone know one of these libraries?
What are their pros and cons?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like sparkledotnet is under dev. no help. no comments. no downloads...
so i wouldn't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I already started with NetSparkle and for now it's a pretty good solution.

Comment: https://github.com/iKenndac/SparkleDotNET/wiki/ - to be honest, I think that SparkleDotNet's documentation is better than NetSparkle's small page http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/documentation (as for Jan 13, 2012). But still, as for me, NetSparkle looks more promising.

Answer (score 6):

[NetSparkle (originally from CodePlex)](http://netsparkle.codeplex.com/) has been forked on GitHub [by jimgraham](https://github.com/jimgraham/NetSparkle) and is on active development there [with many forks](https://github.com/jimgraham/NetSparkle/network). Also it has [packages on NuGet feed](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=netsparkle) - made from one of its forks on GitHub (personally I don't know from which one, but by the name of the packages author I think it's from [this fork](https://github.com/akurdyukov/NetSparkle)).
Documentation is poor. The system itself is stable enough.

[SparkleDotNET](https://github.com/iKenndac/SparkleDotNET) is not in active development [since 2011-11-10](https://github.com/iKenndac/SparkleDotNET/network) and has no contributors.
I have not tried it solely because of this facts.

One more alternative I found useful is [NAppUpdate](https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate). It has clever author, clear infrastructure and good [documentation](http://code972.com/blog/tagged/nappupdate)

Choose wisely.

Comment: NetSparkle is still under active development. We can be found here https://github.com/NetSparkleUpdater/NetSparkle, and we've got packages on NuGet. (Disclaimer: I am the current maintainer and am trying to consolidate the community to a new org.)

Answer (score 4):

I will go with [AutoUpdater.NET : Auto update library for VB.NET and C# Developer](https://github.com/ravibpatel/AutoUpdater.NET). Better documentation and easy to integrate.

I am the author of the library.